# How can I hide search results until the user submits the exposed form?

Tags: views, 8

I have a fairly straightforward view, which exposes a simple keyword filter to the user.

Currently, when I first land on the page containing this view, all records are displayed (*i.e.*, the search results are unfiltered).

How can I alter this behavior, so that no search results are displayed until the user has entered a keyword and submitted the form?

(I'm converting an old Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8. On the D7 site, the view does *not* show search results when I first land on the page. Is this a difference in behavior between the Views implementation in D7 and D8? I can't find anything in the D7 site to suggest that this difference in behavior is caused by a module.)

Comment: Could you just make the keyword filter required?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but it resulted in the "no results found" message being displayed on the initial page view, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can change that under `Advanced` Views options (third column): `Exposed form style:`

[image: Views Exposed Form options]

After you choose `Input required`, you can adjust further options, including the text to display before any filters are active:

[image: Views Input Required Settings]

---

If you're using Better Exposed Filters module it has an option for it too:

> **Input required**
>   Only display results after the user has selected a
>   filter option.

---

It hasn't changed since D7, it works the same in D8 as it did in D7.